# Tile uneven fireplace hearth concrete

Tags: concrete, tile, fireplace, tiling, hearth

I remodel my fireplace and the hearth was poured concrete over:

[image]

I plan to install tiles over the 3 sides

However the surface is not even and not 90 degree

[image]

You can see the bumps from previous concrete which is not possible to remove at this point unless I use a grinder, which will cause a dust mess in our living room.

I looked at this question before but it is not applicable in my case:

[How To Level Uneven Fireplace Hearth Concrete?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/42354/how-to-level-uneven-fireplace-hearth-concrete)

**Questions:**

**Option 1:** Should I try to use mortar and smooth out the surface and make it 90 degree as possible?

**Option 2:** Or should I just go ahead and install tiles with thinset and try to make the tiles as level and as 90 degree as possible by adjusting the thinset amount?

Both are difficult but it would be nice if I can do Option 2. However, I may end up not making the whole thing even / smooth and it will be a mess at the end.

Thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I try to use mortar and smooth out the surface and make it 90 degree as possible?

**NO**- any such patch would be likely to adhere unsuccessfully and would crack and come loose.

> ...install tiles with thinset and try to make the tiles as level and as 90 degree as possible by adjusting the thinset amount?

**YES**- it should be fairly easy to run thick with your thinset, or back-butter the tiles to build it up.
*However*, I question the need to do so.